# ARC - alloc into a strong property.  Creates leak?

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, memory-management, automatic-ref-counting

In ARC, does it create a memory leak to `alloc` into a `@property (strong)`

```
// MyClass.h
@property (strong) NSString *myString;

// MyClass.m
@synthesize myString=_myString;

- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    self.myString = [[NSString alloc] initWithFormat:@"Test %@", otherString];
}
```

I know that in manual memory management, the equivalent would create a leak

```
// MyClass.h
@property (retain) NSString *myString;

// MyClass.m
@synthesize myString=_myString;

- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    self.myString = [[NSString alloc] initWithFormat:@"Test %@", otherString];
}

- (void)dealloc
{
    [_myString release];
}
```

Is ARC able to handle the top example correctly?  Does it optimize away one of the retains?  Or maybe release twice in the dealloc?

Comment: Actually your manual memory management code has a leak.  `[[NSString alloc] init...]` returns an object with a retain count of 1.  Assigning it to `self.myString` uses the compiler-generated setter which retains it, giving it a count of 2.  In `dealloc`, you release it once, giving it a retain count of 1.  Its retain count never goes to zero so it is never deallocated.

Comment: Yes, that was my point in showing the comparison.

Comment: @robmayoff this is not a memory leak under ARC. ARC will insert a `release` at the end of `viewDidLoad`.

Comment: Oops.  I totally missed "the equivalent would create a leak" for some reason.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

This is perfectly valid under ARC.

I would recommend reading the ARC documentation to get more comfortable with trusting what it has to offer. http://clang.llvm.org/docs/AutomaticReferenceCounting.html and Mike Ash has a great blog post on how it works http://www.mikeash.com/pyblog/friday-qa-2011-09-30-automatic-reference-counting.html

Comment: Thanks for the quick reply.  How do you know this? (So that I know where to look in the documentation in the future)

Comment: Because the whole point of ARC is **Automatic Reference Counting**.  The changes to the language were made exactly to enable the compiler to precise lifespan of every object.  If the compiler can't prove the lifespan of an object, it'll warn you.  To put it another way:  If the compiler cannot generate code that provably does not leak or over-release, then it will warn.

Comment: ARC knows that once you stop referencing the created object it can be released. ARC is not magic, it just adds retain/release automatically, what you would have had to add manually before, so you can just program.

Comment: *[Automatic Reference Counting](http://clang.llvm.org/docs/AutomaticReferenceCounting.html#ownership.semantics)* section 4.2: For `__strong` objects, the new pointee is first retained; second, the lvalue is loaded with primitive semantics; third, the new pointee is stored into the lvalue with primitive semantics; and finally, the old pointee is released.

Comment: Also relevant: [Transitioning to ARC Release Notes](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/releasenotes/ObjectiveC/RN-TransitioningToARC/).

Comment: I've finally accepted the advice from WWDC - "stop thinking about retain/release, start thinking about object graphs."  In my code above, I have a pointer (in my @property) to the newly created object - thus it will be kept alive.  Once all pointers to the object are gone, the object memory will be reclaimed.  That's all you need to know to understand ARC.  Actually, I've found that thinking in terms of object graphs has drastically improved my software architecture and programming in general.